# How to set limit for particular no. of sample in jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter, web-api-testing

example ,i want JMeter to run for 100 samples only on 100 thread.

Answer (score 0):

Each JMeter thread (virtual user) executes Samplers upside down for the defined number of iterations.

- If you have 1 Sampler, 100 users and 1 iteration - you will have 100 executions
- If you have 1 Sampler, 100 users and 2 iterations - you will have 200 executions
- If you have 1 Sampler, 200 users and 2 iterations - you will have 400 executions
- If you have 2 Samplers, 200 users and 2 iterations - you will have 800 executions
- etc

The number of users and iterations can be set in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group).

- If you want to execute a particular sampler only by the 1st user - go for [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and use [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) to determine the number of the current user
- If you want to execute a particular sampler i.e. 5 times and others 100 times - go for [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)

Comment: Hii, thanks for your reply , how can i control the no. Of thread and can you comment down the formula to set the sampler limit?.